# Prepopulate django filter horizontal in admin

Tags: python, django, model, filter, django-admin

I have a simple Django project about tennis network. And I would like to prepopulate a filter horizontal in my admin interface with the name of player. Also, some player can play at 7PM and the others at 9PM. My **model.py** is as follow :

```
class thursday(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    time_first = models.ManyToManyField(player, related_name='firsttime', verbose_name='7PM')
    time_second = models.ManyToManyField(player, related_name='secondtime', verbose_name='9PM')
```

and my **admin.py** :

```
class ThursdayAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('date', 'status')
    search_fields = ['date']
    filter_horizontal = ('time_first', 'time_second',)
    list_filter = ('date',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('date', 'time_first', 'time_second', 'status')
        }),
    )
```

Obviously, I would like to prepopulate the "time_first" filter horizontal with only player which can play at 7PM, and idem for the second.
How is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help. I find a so nice solution on the [davydany's website](http://davydany.com/post/8701385688/django-excluding-with-limit-choices-to) :

```
time_first = models.ManyToManyField(player, related_name='firsttime', verbose_name='7PM', limit_choices_to={'id__in': player.objects.filter(preference='7PM')})
```

I hope this will help others.

Comment: Can you explain what your code @rphonika does. (in simple english)

Answer (score 1):

You could always create a custom form

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = MyModel
    time_first = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Player.objects.filter(......), required=False, widget=FilteredSelectMultiple)
```